# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Error htmlfile: Unknown runtime error, updatePanelElement.innerHTML=rendering

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I get this error when debugging my ASP.NET web application after I trigger an UpdatePanel:

[image: ASP.NET htmlfile: Unknown runtime error updatePanelElement.innerHTML=rendering]

htmlfile: Unknown runtime error

and "updatePanelElement.innerHTML=rendering" is highlighted in a ScriptResource.axd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen because I've got my UpdatePanel within an ordered list <ol> container.  And I've got list item <li> tags within my UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate.

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ...>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <li id="lione" runat="server">...</li>
            <li id="litwo" runat="server">...</li>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            ...
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

It makes sense to me this way, but I guess I'll need to rethink my page layout.

Comment: That will actually render as <ol><li>...</li><div id="updatePanel1"><li>...</li></div><li>...</li></ol>. I don't know if that's the problem or not, but it certainly is invalid html.

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue, But with a Timer, I just move the timer out of the UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same issue. In my case Page (Table) was not designed properly. Here is the issue details in my scenario:

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label id="Lb1" runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UP1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
       <!-- controls in Update Panel-->
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Button id="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have changed to

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label id="Lb1" runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
**<tr>
<td>**
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UP1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
       <!-- controls in Update Panel-->
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
**</td>
</tr>**
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Button id="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Issue resolved moving Update panel in to another table row.
So I strongly believe proper screen design should address this type of issues.

Comment: I were having the same problem here and this post solve it. Thank suneelk.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the explanation above - I found a solution by wrapping the UpdatePanel with the li that needs to be updated by the event. Hope that helps.

e.g.

```
<li>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelCustInfo" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <label>State:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateProvince" AutoPostBack="False" runat="server" CssClass="adminInput">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

had the same error placed the update panel between the  tags by mistake instead of the nested  tags. That fix did it so i took it from this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="Server">
<ContentTemplate>
<td>

    //code here

</td>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</table>
```

to :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="Server">
<ContentTemplate>

    //code here


</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but solved.

I am nesting html form inside UpdatePanel.  Simply removing the Form tag solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To say this drove me crazy is an understatement.  I received the same error the OP described, and played around with my HTML trying to figure out why I couldn't write to a div within a p tag.  In the end, I duplicated my page HTML just to screw around with the HTML arranged on my page, and found that it had nothing to do with the particular UpdatePanel I was fiddling with.  I had javascript script tags in my body content at the bottom of my page, I don't know why exactly, but IE8 hated this arrangement.  I was able to remove all script within my body content, and placed it in my head tag of my page, and this issue went away.  HTH